# Is it possible to add a range to UIElementCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add a huge amount (100K) of Rectangle to a Canvas, programmatically. Unfortunately my code is slow if I do this one by one via Add(). Since I exactly know the number of new elements, I'm looking for a method to first initialize a set of new instances and then add just this set to the UIElementCollection (Canvas children). I was looking for a method like AddRange, CopyFrom (array) or so. Any idea?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Are you trying to draw individual pixels on the screen? Do you simply have a lot of content you want users to scroll through? Please explain the use case.

Comment: If you're trying to draw 100k rectangles, you may want to consider DirectX. WPF is a great tool, but that's really pushing the boundaries of what it's designed to do.

Comment: It's a zoomable map. Each rectangle represents a clickable tile. Normally the zoom would inhibit the map to render more than 10K tiles, but as long as I'm developing I need a larger overview, hence 100K.

Comment: I think you would be better off drawing fewer tiles, say 100 where each combines the images from several smaller tiles. Then you could handle zooming in by replacing the tiles with smaller ones when only a few were visible.

Comment: Thanks Rune. Assumed I did this, I'd need to dispatch the point and click events to the individual tiles, any idea?

Comment: @yacc see my answer after reading your last comment.

Comment: I know that there are components that do this for you. Check out GitHub for instance. Apart from that, check out the answer from @AnjumSKhan

Comment: Yes, it seems like trees of Rectangle may be the right approach. That is, grouping four neighboring rects to form a representative that is used for the next lower level of detail (all rects are equally sized).

Comment: @all Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no `AddRange` or similar function for the `UIElementCollection`. So you cannot add many elements at the same time.

But as the comments to your question says, you are probably doing something wrong if you are adding 100k elements to the same canvas.

What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question and comments, I recommend using a tree like structure, or a hashtable. 
Rect1-> Rect11, Rect11, Rect111, Rect1111 ...
Rect2-> ...

You show Rect1, Rect2 etc, and then see which tile/rect user clicks, and change view accordingly. Note that your Rect11 could be another hashtable for further zooming and so on.

This looks like best approach as you know before hand number of rectangles.

And for finding which tile was clicked , you can use Routing like below :

```
<Canvas Rectangle.MouseDown="Rectangle_MouseDown">
        <Rectangle x:Name="rect1" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="32" Canvas.Left="20" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="32" Width="37"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="rect2" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="24" Canvas.Left="121" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="32" Width="50"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="8" Canvas.Left="48" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="99" Width="9"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="rect3" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="41" Canvas.Left="121" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="99" Width="73"/>        
    </Canvas>
```

///

```
 private void Rectangle_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle rect = (Rectangle)e.Source;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(rect.Name);
        }
```